# Displaying error message in html form with php

Tags: php, html, forms

I would like to display error messages in my html form through php variables which are populated with the values which are assigned in 'register-form_v2.php'.

Could someone enlighten me why the variables, which I would like to echo out in the form do not hold any values? Because when I submit the form I don't get the desired error messages displayed to the user, it simply directs me to the url defined in the if statement, but nothing more.

Below the file with the html form and the variable / error message I would like to echo out.

```
<?php

include "register-form_v2.php";

?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>

    <style>
        #wrapper {
            width: 100%;
            margin: 0 auto;
            background-color: aliceblue;
        }

        form {
            display: flex;
            flex-direction: column;
            width: 50%;
            margin: auto;
            padding: 20px;
            background-color: antiquewhite;
        }

        .input-wrapper {
            margin: 20px;
            font-size: 20px;
        }

        .red-text {
            color: red;
        }

    </style>
    
    <div id="wrapper">

        <form action="register-form_v2.php" method="POST">
        
        <div class="red-text" ><?php echo $errors['email'];?> Test, this displays :=)</div>
            <div class="input-wrapper">
                <label for="email">E-mail</label> <br>
                <input id="email" type="text" name="email" value="">
            </div>
            <div class="red-text" ><?php echo $errors['username'];?></div>
            <div class="input-wrapper">
                <label for="username">Username</label> <br>
                <input type="text" name="username" value="">
            </div>
            <div class="red-text" > <?php echo $errors['password']; ?></div>
            <div class="input-wrapper" >
                <label for="password">Password</label> <br>
                <input type="text" name="password" value="">
            </div>
            <div class="red-text" > <?php echo $errors['password']; ?></div>
            <div class="input-wrapper">
                <label for="password-check">Password-check</label> <br>
                <input type="text" name="password-check" value="">
            </div>

            <div class="input-wrapper">
                <button type="submit" name="login-submit">Login</button>
            </div>

        </form>

    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

The 2nd file with my form validation.

```
<?php

$errors = array('fields' => '', 'email' => '', 'username' => '', 'password' => '');
$fields_err = '';

if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {

    require "dbConnect.php";
    
   
    
    $email = $_POST["email"];
    $username = $_POST["username"];
    $password = $_POST["password"];
    $password_check = $_POST["password-check"];

    
    

    if( empty($email) || empty($username) || empty($password) || empty($password_check)) {
        header("location: SignUp.php?error=emptyfields&mail=".$email."&uid=".$username);
        $errors['fields'] = 'You need to fill in the fields';
        $fields_err = ' doh it went wrong no fields ';
        echo 'asdfasdf';
    }
    //checking for valid email
    elseif(!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL) && !preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z0-9]*$/", $username)) {
        $errors['email'] = 'please use a valid email and user ID, user ID can only use alphanummeric values';
        header("location: SignUp.php?error=invalidmail_and_uid");
        exit();
        //cjecl
    } elseif(!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
        $errors['email'] = 'something not right there with your email budy';
        header("location: SignUp.php?error=invalidmail&uid=".$username);
        exit();
    }
    // checking for valid username
    elseif(!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z0-9]*$/", $username)) {
        $errors['username'] = 'your username is invalid, your username needs to include only numbers or letters';
        header("location: SignUp.php?error=invalidUid&mail=".$email);
        exit();
    }
    //checking for password length
    elseif(strlen(trim($password)) < 11) {
        $errors['password'] = 'your password must include at least 11 characters';
        header("location: SignUp.php?error=nopswMatch&uid=".$username."&mail=".$email);
        exit();
    }
    //checking if password and password_check match
    elseif($password !== $password_check) {
        $errors['password'] = 'your password confirmation does not match';
        header("location: SignUp.php?error=nopswMatch&uid=".$username."&mail=".$email);
        exit();
    } else {
        $sql = "SELECT username FROM dudes WHERE username=:username";
    
                //check if username is already taken
        if(!$stmt = $conn->prepare($sql)) {
 
            //Bind variables to the prepared statemnet as parameters
            header("location: SignUp.php?error=sqlerror");
            exit();
        } else {

            $stmt->bindParam(":username", $username, PDO::PARAM_STR);
            $stmt->execute();
            
            $result_check = $stmt->rowCount();

            if($result_check == 1) {
                $errors['username'] = 'the user name has already been taken';
                echo "The userName has already been taken";
            } 
            else {
                echo "great success";
                // insert code here
                $sql = "INSERT INTO dudes (email, username, password) VALUES (:email, :username, :password)";

                if(!$stmt = $conn->prepare($sql)) {
                    header("location: SignUp.php?error=prepStmtFail");
                } else {
                    $stmt->bindParam(':email', $email);
                    $stmt->bindParam(':username', $username);
                    $stmt->bindParam(':password', $param_password);
                    // hash the password
                    $param_password = password_hash($password, PASSWORD_BCRYPT);

                if($stmt->execute()){

                    header("location: SignUp.php?signup=success");
                    exit();
                }
                
                }

            

            }
        }
    }
}

?>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can temporary store your error in $_SESSION variable.
Or you can add your error in the $_GET variable

Example :

```
// php part :
session_start();

$_SESSION['errors']['password'] = 'your password confirmation does not match';
header("location: SignUp.php?error=nopswMatch&uid=".$username."&mail=".$email);

// html part : 
if(isset($_SESSION['errors'])) {
    foreach ($_SESSION['errors'] as $key => $value) {
        echo '<div class="red-text" >'. $_SESSION['errors']['email']. 'Test, this displays :=)</div>';
    }
}
unset($_SESSION['errors']);
```

OR

```
// php part :
header("location: SignUp.php?error=your password confirmation does not match&uid=".$username."&mail=".$email);


// html part : 
if(isset($_GET['error'])) {
    echo '<div class="red-text" >'. $_GET['error']. 'Test, this displays :=)</div>';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A variable value can be used in a single page only. Since you populated the $error array in another php file you can't use that variable in other pages.

What you could do is use a $_SESSION[] variable which is accessible in any pages that uses session_start() at top of the code.

Or
use this in your login or signup page

```
<?php

if(isset($_GET['error']) && $_GET['error']=='emptyfield')
{
 $errors['email'] = 'All field are compulsory";
}
?>
```

Now you can use $errors['email'] in your form